# SyntaxHighlighter is acting funny

Tags: javascript, syntax-highlighting

I am using [SyntaxHighlighter](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/) on my [website](http://derek1906.site50.net/works/jfont.php) and it is acting very strange. I put my codes in `<pre>`s and used `SyntaxHighlighter.all()`, and what I got are in every single codes, it inserted 1~2 extra lines.

Where's the problem? I checked everything and everything is fine. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about SyntaxHighlighter, but in general, the `<pre>` tag works effective immediately, LF and CR everything. When Syntax Highlighter does its conversion, it might be respecting these line feeds as well. For example:

```
<pre>
  There will be a line before and after this
</pre>
```

vs.

```
<pre>There will be no lines</pre>
```

We're used to writing well-formatted and well-indented code, but with pre tags you have to make an exception. Looking at your source code, I think you're doing it the top way.

Comment: Ok, I removed the tabs and it works fine. The line numbers are correct, but now the line height is not correct... Oh my god, it is so annoying...